# How is the input to another command resolved in bash? How we redirect errors and pass the input?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I read the following snippet:

```
mysql -u $USER -p $PASS <<EOF 2> /dev/null  
CREATE DATABASE students;    
EOF
```

Ok. So this runs the `mysql` client and does a `CREATE DATABASE`.
My question is how come the `2>/dev/null` is not considered part of the `EOF`?
I assume that the `<<` is for the input to the program `mysql` after it has connected with the user and password parameters.
So how `2>/dev/null` is not part of the `<<`?

Answer (score 3):

Because words in the shell are separated by whitespace. The here-doc terminator is a word, so it does not consume the rest of the line.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation

Comment: The documents don't explicitly state this, but also note that the contents of the here document begin on the next logical line of the script, not immediately following the terminator.

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses a *Heredoc*, and the shell ultimately interprets this as a redirection in itself. It is treated like other forms of redirection.

Equivalent Examples:

Herestring:

```
mysql -u $USER -p $PASS<<<"CREATE DATABASE students;" 2>/dev/null
```

Echo:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE students;" | mysql -u $USER -p $PASS 2>/dev/null
```

I shamelessly recommend reading further at Greg's Wiki, because it is an excellent resource:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput